# linear algebra eigenvalues/vectors and finding an expression for $A^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi guys I have a linear algebra question I am trying to work through (here is the question)

[image: Question]

I have worked through part a of the question how I think I am supposed to. 
I assume you can just set $x$ as any number when the question states that is a real number and this is what I have done. I have been able to get an answer although it doesn't seem like the right one. Can anyone confirm this is correct or wrong and if its wrong where I have gone wrong.

[image: Attempted answer]

Also I am not sure at all how to do the second part of the question, so if anyone could help with that it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For future reference, it is easier on your Readers if you use [MathJax/LaTex](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to format your Question.  Sideways images such as your work above are very hard on the eyes! For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Also, please type your question.  The image of the question you provided is not searchable.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answerer indicates, you went wrong in your computation of the determinant when you changed a $+$ to a $\cdot$.

---

### Part 1:

We can write $A = B + xI$, where
$$
B = \pmatrix{
0&0&1\\
0&0&1\\
1&1&0
}
$$
If $\mu_1 \leq \mu_2 \leq \mu_3$ denote the eigenvalues of $B$, then $A$ will have the same eigenvectors with
$$
\lambda_1 = \mu_1 + x\\
\lambda_2 = \mu_2 + x\\
\lambda_3 = \mu_3 + x
$$
So it suffices to find the eigenvalues of $B$.

After computing the determinant correctly, you should end up with
$$
\mu_1 = -\sqrt 2\\
\mu_2 = 0\\
\mu_3 = \sqrt 2
$$

I will leave to you the computation of the corresponding eigenvectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$.  Neat fact: because $B$ is symmetric with non-repeating eigenvalues, you should find that the eigenvectors are mutually orthogonal.

---

### Part 2:

Since $x = 0$, we have $A = B$.

Using your eigenvectors, you can now come up with a matrix $P$ such that $B = PDP^{-1}$, where
$$
P = \pmatrix{\\v_1 & v_2 & v_3\\ &}, \quad
D = \pmatrix{\mu_1\\&\mu_2\\&&\mu_3}
$$
From there, we have $A^n = [PDP^{-1}]^n = PD^nP^{-1}$.  You should find that $D^n$ is easy to compute.

**Neat trick:** take $v_1,v_2,$ and $v_3$ to each be unit vectors.  If you do so, we'll have $P^{-1} = P^T$.

Comment: thanks for your response i am able to get the eigenvectors from μ1=−1 μ2=0 μ3=2, 
$$μ1=1,1,-2$$ $$μ2=1,0,-1$$ $$μ3=1,0,1$$ although i am still unsure of how you got the eigenvalues since i cannot get the same results. am i correct in using x=1 or should it be something else ?. when i do use x=1 i'm not completely sure of what to do when i get to this point 
$$(1−λ)(λ^2−2λ+1)+1(0−(1−λ))$$ what i thought i should do was 
$$(1−λ)(λ^2−2λ+1)+1(0−1+λ))$$ 
$$(1−λ)(λ^2−2λ+1)+(−1+λ)$$ 
$$(1−λ)(λ^2−2λ+1−1+λ)$$ 
$$(1−λ)(λ^2−λ)$$ 
from here i dont know. i'm preety sure im going about this the wrong way

Comment: Use $x=0{}{}{}$

Comment: For $x=1$, you should get $0,1,3$. Reading your comment, it really seems like you didn't understand my answer. Do you understand what I'm saying about $A$ and $B$?

Comment: to be honest i didnt really understand your answer A=B+xI. I thought this was just the characteristic determinant which allows you to get the eigenvalues. It seems like im calculating the determinant incorrectly, since even when i use x=0 i cant get the same answer.
$$(0-λ)((0-λ)(0-λ)-1)+1(0-λ)$$
$$(0-λ)(-λ^2-1)+1(0-λ)$$
$$(0-λ)(-λ^2-λ-1)$$

Comment: @dmnte $(-\lambda)(-\lambda)=\lambda^2$

Comment: yeah sorry
$$(0−λ)((0−λ)(0−λ)−1)+1(0−λ)$$
$$(0−λ)(λ^2−1)+1(0−λ)$$
$$(0−λ)(λ^2−λ−1)$$
unless ive done this wrong i cant see how you get eigenvalues of μ1=−1 μ2=0 μ3=2 seeing as you need to use quadratic formula for this polynomial.

Comment: I've made a mistake, see my latest edit. Your mistake here is that your last + should be a -. You should end up with $-\lambda^3 + 2\lambda$.

Comment: lol thanks for your help!, i've finally been able to get the right answer for the first part at least. now to start on the second part.

Comment: I tried the second part and was just having some issues understanding.what I have so far is:
$$P=
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
       -2 & -1 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
$$D=
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
$$PDP^{-1}=
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
       -2 & -1 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
sorry, i didnt really understand what you meant with$A^n=[PDP^{−1}]^n=PD^nP^{−1}$. Could you please explain further or show the next steps ?

Comment: Your $D$ should have $\sqrt2$ on the diagonal, not $1$. Can you compute $D^n$ in terms of $n$?

Comment: I'm also not sure about your $P$

Comment: sorry i used the wrong values, if i use the vectors from part 1 it should b:

$$P=
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 &-1 \\
        -\sqrt{2} & \sqrt{2} & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

the putting in the next values should give:

$$D=
        \begin{matrix}
        -\sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & \sqrt{2} \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

so then 

$$PDP^1=
        \begin{matrix}
        -\sqrt{2} & 0 & -2 \\
        -\sqrt{2} & 0 & -\sqrt{2} \\
        2 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: i think that is right now ? sorry no i cannot compute D^{n} in terms of n, im learning this on my own for an entrance exam

Comment: Start by trying to do that, then.  Or, post a new question about the particular parts you're stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first part:

You should think of $x$ as a placeholder for any real number and leave it there while calculating the eigenvalues. That means that you have to compute

$$\det \begin{pmatrix} x- \lambda & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & x-\lambda & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & x-\lambda\end{pmatrix} = ?$$

and then find out for which $\lambda$ this expression equals $0$.

In your calculation you chose $x=1$ but made some mistakes during the computation. E.g. from the 3rd to the 4th line you just transformed a '$+$' into a '$\cdot$'.

Regarding the second task, I suggest you leave $x$ in there and just compute $A^2,A^3,A^4$ and see if you find some regularity.

If you have any other problems, leave a comment and I will extent my answer :)

Comment: thanks for your response ive tried what you said (leaving the x and find out for which expression i get 0) but am having a bit of trouble. this is what i get:

$$(x-λ)(x^2-xλ-xλ-λ^2-1)+1(0-(x-λ))$$
$$(x-λ)(x^2-2xλ-λ^2-1-x+λ)$$
$$(x-λ)(x^2-2xλ-λ^2-1-x+λ)$$ so then x=2
$$(2-λ)(4-4λ-λ^2-1-2+λ)$$
$$(2-λ)(-λ^2-3λ+1)$$
i'm not sure if i am going about this wrong i probably misunderstood you. If you could show me what you mean that would be great.