# confirmation of answer: find an expression for $A^n$ for any positive integer N

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Hi I have a linear algebra question that im not sure if I am doing correctly. The question is to get the eigenvalus and vectors and then find an expression for $A^n$. If someone could confirm that my working out and answer is correct it would be much appreciated.

$$A= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & x & 0 \\ x & 0 & -x \\ 0 & -x & 0\end{pmatrix} 
$$

I got the eigenvectors:

$$ 
    v_1=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\ \sqrt 2
    \ \\ -1\end{pmatrix},\quad
    v_2=\begin{pmatrix}
    -1 \\ \sqrt 2
    \ \\ 1
    \end{pmatrix},\quad
    v_3=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\ 0 \\ 1
    \end{pmatrix}.
$$

after doing the schur triangulation I got:

$$ 
    U^TAU=\begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}\\ -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\ \\ \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix},\quad
   \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & x & 0\\ x & 0 & -x
    \ \\ 0 & -x & 0\end{pmatrix},\quad
 \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} & \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} & 0
    \ \\ -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}
$$

after multiplying the matrices i got.

$$ 
    A^n=\begin{pmatrix}
    (\sqrt 2x)^n & 0 & 0\\ 0 & (\sqrt 2x)^n & 0\ \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},
$$

Can anyone confirm wether this is right or not, and if not where I have gone wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Haven't checked the working, but the answer must be wrong because if you substitute $n=0$ you don't get $I$ as you should.  Also, if you substitute $n=1$ you don't get $A$.

Comment: I don't quite understand: how did you get those eigenvectors you say if the matrix $\;A\;$ is an undetermined one ?? I mean, how come they do not depend on $\;x\;$ ? It looks like you decided $\;x=1\;$ to choose the eigenvectors....this doesn't look right.

Comment: Yeah, for A I have made x=1. Yes this is most likely not right, that is why I put it here asking for help since i'm not sure where i'm going wrong.

Comment: Alright so I think your calculations are correct I have checked some. There is an error in your judgement in the last step. So you transform $A$ into a diagonal matrix using the eigenvectors as the basis so you write $A=M^{-1}DM$ where $D$ is diagonal. But note $A^n$ becomes $A^n = E^{-1}D^nE$. Please check that.

Comment: Your matrix $U$ is not actually orthogonal

Comment: It is sufficient to answer the question for $x = 1$, since $(xA)^n = x^n A^n$ for any constant $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Since I reserve $\;x\;$ for polynomials and/or linear equations, let's write

$$A= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & a & 0 \\ a & 0 & -a \\ 0 & -a & 0\end{pmatrix} 
$$

Now the characteristic polynomial:

$$|xI-A|=\begin{vmatrix} x & -a & 0 \\ -a & x & a \\ 0 & a & x\end{vmatrix}=x^3-2a^2x=x(x-\sqrt2\,a)(x+\sqrt2\,a)$$

Making the safe assumption $\;a\neq 0\;$ (otherwise the question's completely trivial), and assuming we're working over a field with characteristic $\,\neq2\;$ and where $\;\sqrt2\;$ exists, we get here three different eigenvalues which render our matrix diagonalizable (which is clear if we're over the reals or the complex as the matrix is symmetric).

We thus **know** there exists invertible $\;P\;$ s.t.

$$P^{-1}AP=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt2\,a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \!\!-\sqrt2\,a\end{pmatrix}=:D $$

$\;P\;$ can be found by means of the eigenvectors, which surprisingly enough (for me, at least), are the ones you wrote *without any need to input* $\;x=1\;$ !

Thus, from the above we get

$$P^{-1}A^nP=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2^{n/2}\,a^n & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \!\!(-2)^{n/2}\,a^n\end{pmatrix}=D^n$$

so to answer your question just do

$$A^n=PD^nP^{-1}$$

Comment: To perhaps lessen your surprise: for any matrix $Mv = \lambda v$, then $aMv = a\lambda v$.  So, for every $a \neq 0$, the $A$ will have the same eigenvectors and proportional eigenvalues.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh, I realized that while solving the exercise. Thanks.

Comment: Also, note that $P$ may necessarily be chosen to be orthogonal since $A$ is real and symmetric.  I find computing this $P$ far preferable to computing a $3 \times 3$ inverse by the usual method.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Its going to take me a bit to go through it an understand it. ill write again when I have problems =P

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I don't think we can say $\;A\;$ is real (this isn't given), though I guess it is a prudent choice.

Comment: @Timbuc even if $A$ is not real, it is certainly normal.  The fact that the unitary change of basis may be taken to consist of real vectors may be taken as a neat coincidence.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom If you get into inner product considerations, and thus the base field is either the reals or the complex, then eigenvectors of *different* eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are always perpendicular, so not so big a coincidence.

Comment: But we can't always diagonalize a complex matrix with a real orthogonal change of basis

Comment: @Omnomnomnom We can in case the matrix is symmetric...but all this is mooth as we're guessing.

Comment: im doing this by hand and having trouble getting the same answer. to confirm 

$$P= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & \sqrt 2\ & -\sqrt 2\ \\
 1 & -1 & -1\end{pmatrix} 
$$

Comment: @dmnte Well, yes. Though that matrix's colums aren't *exactly* the eigenvectors you found. For some reason, instead of choosing **your** $\;v_2\;$ you chose for the matrix's third column $\;-v_2\;$ ...It doesn't matter, of course: it gives the same result.

Comment: sorry i just cant get the right answeri assume i must be doing the inverse of P incorrectly.can i ask what you got for $P^-1$ ?

Comment: @dmnte With the help of the classic adjoint it goes pretty smoothly: $$P^{-1}=-\frac1{4\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}-2\sqrt2&0&-2\sqrt2\\ -\sqrt2&-2&\sqrt2\\-\sqrt2&2&\sqrt2\end{pmatrix}=$$$$= \begin{pmatrix}\frac12&0&\frac12\\\frac14&\frac1{2\sqrt2}&-\frac14\\\frac14&-\frac1{2\sqrt2}&-\frac14\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: multiplying matrices Im not getting the correct D.
$$ 
    P^{-1}A=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0\\ \frac{1}{2\sqrt {2}} & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2\sqrt {2}}
    \ \\ \frac{1}{2\sqrt {2}} & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2\sqrt {2}}\end{pmatrix}
$$
then ($P^{-1}A$)P
$$ 
    (P^{-1}A)P=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & \sqrt {2}a & \sqrt {2}a\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt {2}}a & (\frac{1}{\sqrt {2}}a+\frac{\sqrt {2}}{2}a) & (-\frac{1}{\sqrt {2}}a+\frac{\sqrt {2}}{2}a) \\ 0 & (\frac{1}{\sqrt {2}}a+\frac{\sqrt {2}}{2}a) & (-\frac{1}{\sqrt {2}}a+\frac{\sqrt {2}}{2}a)\end{pmatrix}
$$
Is there an obvious thing im doing wrong?